# Shell Scripting How to combine variables and wildcard

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a simple shell script to run several commands at once. I can't figure out how to do this:

```
'mkdir -p $FULL_BACKUP_PATH; cp -r $FULL_PATH/* $FULL_BACKUP_PATH/.;'
```

If I use single quotes, the variables don't get the values, if I use double quotes, the wildcard does not expand.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
mkdir -p "${FULL_BACKUP_PATH}"; cp -r "${FULL_PATH}/*" "${FULL_BACKUP_PATH}"
```

Variables inside double quotes get expanded, variables inside single quotes do not. Always put variables inside double quotes if they are paths/directories in case they have spaces in them so the double quotes "hold them together".

If the code appears in  shell script that starts with a shebang like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

you can temporarily add `-xv` after `bash` to see the script expanded as it is executed and that will help you debug it, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
```